# How to merge aql query with iterative traversal

Tags: traversal, arangodb, aql

I want to query a collection in ArangoDB using AQL, and at each node in the query, expand the node using a traversal.

I have attempted to do this by calling the traversal as a subquery using a LET statement within the collection query. 
The result set for the traversal is empty, even though the query completes.

```
FOR ne IN energy
    FILTER ne.identifier == "12345"
    LET ne_edges = (
    FOR v, e IN 1..1 ANY ne relation
        RETURN e
    )
    RETURN MERGE(ne, {"edges": ne_edges})
```

---

```
[
  {
    "value": 123.99,
    "edges": []
  }
]
```

I have verified there are edges, and the traversal returns correctly when it is not executed as a subquery.

It seems as if the initial query is completing before a result is returned from the subquery, giving the result below.

What am I missing? or is there a better way?

Comment: The way you do your query is correct. It must be a data related issue. Are you sure the edges your saw reference the objects your are trying to filter with `ne.identifier == "12345"`?

Comment: BTW, what is `energy`? Is it a collection? If so, the output you posted should be a bit different. It should also contain some system attributes like `_key` and `_id`. May be that is a problem. When you do a traversal you must specify and object or an _id value of a starting object. If you `ne` is not an object which have an `_id` attribute the traversal would not work.

Comment: @PeterLiapin energy is a collection, yes. The code i gave was dummy code and was only meant to be representative rather than an exact output. I should have mentioned this in my question, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two way to do this. This first is easier to understand but the second is more compact. For the examples below, I have a vertex collection test2 and an edge collection testEdge that links parent and child items within test2

Using Collect:

```
let seed = (FOR testItem IN test2
            FILTER testItem._id in ['test2/Q1', 'test2/Q3'] 
            RETURN testItem._id)

let traversal = (FOR seedItem in seed
    FOR v, e IN 1..1 ANY seedItem
    testEdge
RETURN {seed: seedItem, e_to: e._to})

for t in traversal
COLLECT seeds = t.seed INTO groups = t.e_to
return {myseed: seeds, mygroups: groups}
```

Above we first get the items we want to traverse through (seed), then we perform the traversal and get an object that has the seed .id and the related edges
Then we finally use `collect into` to group the results

Using array expansion

```
FOR testItem IN test2
    FILTER testItem._id in ['test2/Q1', 'test2/Q3']
    LET testEdges = (
    FOR v, e IN 1..1 ANY testItem testEdge
        RETURN e
    )
RETURN {myseed: testItem._id, mygroups: testEdges[*]._to}
```

This time we combine the seed search and the traversal by using the `let` statement. then we use array expansion to group items

In either case, I end up with something that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "myseed": "test2/Q1",
    "mygroups": [
      "test2/Q1-P5-2",
      "test2/Q1-P6-3",
      "test2/Q1-P4-1"
    ]
  },
  {
    "myseed": "test2/Q3",
    "mygroups": [
      "test2/Q3",
      "test2/Q3"
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: I tried both approaches and while I do like the second approach it still returns an empty. I'm not sure why it has worked for your system and not mine, what version of ArangoDB are you using, and on what OS? I'm currently use 3.4 on Windows 10...
Thankfully the first approach works, but is not ideal in my scenario

Comment: I just tried it again and both approaches work on my machine. I am have arangodb  3.4.0 (community) running in the official arangodb docker image in my Mac. Maybe it is data related? If you add some sample data I can try it in my machine. The only reason I can think for it not to work is that the input to the array expansion is not actually an array. Then it would return empty.